# Java Image Resize code not working

Tags: java, servlets, image-resizing

I am working on a program in which I have to resize the image before saving it into the database in order to save the space on the server. The code has been working fine for years but suddenly it stopped working on the remote server but it is working fine for the localhost.I have also contacted the remote server maintenance team but having got any problem from their side. I am unable to understand the problem. Please help me to solve this.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*;
public class Image_Rendar
{
public byte[] resizeImageAsJPG(byte[] pImageData, int pMaxWidth) throws IOException
    {

            // Create an ImageIcon from the image data
            ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(pImageData);
            int width = imageIcon.getIconWidth();
            int height = imageIcon.getIconHeight();
            //mLog.info("imageIcon width: #0  height: #1", width, height);
            // If the image is larger than the max width, we need to resize it
            if (pMaxWidth > 0 && width > pMaxWidth) 
            {
                // Determine the shrink ratio
                double ratio = (double) pMaxWidth / imageIcon.getIconWidth();
              //  mLog.info("resize ratio: #0", ratio);
                height = (int) (imageIcon.getIconHeight() * ratio);
                width = pMaxWidth;
              //  mLog.info("imageIcon post scale width: #0  height: #1", width, height);
            }
            // Create a new empty image buffer to "draw" the resized image into
            BufferedImage bufferedResizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            // Create a Graphics object to do the "drawing"
            Graphics2D g2d = bufferedResizedImage.createGraphics();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
            // Draw the resized image
            g2d.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, width, height, null);
            g2d.dispose();
            // Now our buffered image is ready
            // Encode it as a JPEG
            ByteArrayOutputStream encoderOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(encoderOutputStream);
            //encoder.encode(bufferedResizedImage);
            byte[] resizedImageByteArray = encoderOutputStream.toByteArray();
            ImageIO.write(bufferedResizedImage, "jpeg", encoderOutputStream);
            return resizedImageByteArray;
            }
   }
```

After Printing the Stacktrace I have got this.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.image.FetcherInfo.getFetcherInfo(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.add(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.startProduction(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.addConsumer(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.startProduction(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.startProduction(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage.addWatcher(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Image_Rendar.resizeImageAsJPG(Image_Rendar.java:15)
at Profile_img_upload.doPost(Profile_img_upload.java:103)
```

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions?

Comment: No, I am unable to see any exception i have requested for the error log and haven't found any.

Comment: Insufficient information to help you.

Comment: @john16384 After Printing the stack trace I have got this. And i have updated the question with the stack trace. Please help me on this.

Comment: Which line is throwing the NPE? I looks like it is  pImageData, are you sure that is not null?

Comment: line 15 in this class file. And the code is " ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(pImageData); "

Comment: Are you sure, pImageData is not null? How are you reading that/getting that data?

Comment: yes i am sure cause it is running fine on my localhost server. And i am reading this data using this code.  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload sfu  = new ServletFileUpload(factory); 
    List items = sfu.parseRequest(request);
    FileItem file = (FileItem) items.get(0);
    FileItem  usergender = (FileItem) items.get(1);
    String gender =  usergender.getString();

Comment: That doesn't really show that you know pImageData is not null. It is quite possible that you are missing the required image decoder for pImageData. Is pImageData a jpg? What jvm are you using on the remote host?

Comment: I am using the shared server and deploying the application using Parallel Plesk panel so, I don't have the idea what jvm they are using. Although this functionality was running smoothly on the remote server also but suddenly something went wrong.

Comment: `new ImageIcon(pImageData);` is throwing a null pointer exception. So the bottom line is pImageData does not contain valid image data that ImageIcon can read. You need to verify/fix pImageData somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the remote server was migrated to Java 7 or later. Starting in Java 7, the `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg` package was removed ([Source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html)).

Also worth a read: [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs 
That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, i have gone through the link you shared and got   lots of valuable info. And following this i have used ImageIO instead of JPEGImageEncoder. But still facing the problem, i have updated the question with the stack trace. Please help.